# Developing XSLT with TDD/BDD

Tags: unit-testing, xslt, tdd, rspec, bdd

I've been assigned the task of creating an XSLT transform on an XML dump from a database.  Being a believer of Test/Behavior Driven Development I was wondering if anyone has attempted it before or has advice about how to go about it.

My gut reaction is to test this 'black box' with rspec.  Is there a unit testing framework out there for testing XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently found myself asking a similar question, but with Java rather than Ruby.  I was writing an XSLT stylesheet and wanted to have some automated tests for it.  In the end, the approach I adopted was to use the XSLT stylesheet to transform some sample XML documents and then run XPath queries on each of the results.  I guess this is much the same approach as your 'gut reaction'.

A quick Google turns up a number of XSLT unit-testing frameworks, but most of these appear to target Java, not Ruby.  I chose not to use any of them with my project since almost all of them seem to no longer be actively maintained.

Comment: Yes, what your describing was my plan.  Thanks for confirming that what I was thinking is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a BDD framework for testing XSLT called [xspec](http://code.google.com/p/xspec/) which is based on rspec developed by Jeni Tennison.